# How To Create Nested Gridview in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to know how to create nested gridview in ASP.NET Core MVC.

We may be able find a lot of example to create it in old ASP.NET 2.0 like the picture in below?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Makrokode, there is no GridView Control in asp.net core. In asp.net core, you could only design table with tr/td to meet your requirement by default. Or you could consider using any other third party library.

Comment: Any suggestion for third party library?